# How to get the "with" statement feature in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, with-statement, strict

When putting Javascript into strict mode, the "with" statement is no longer allowed.  How could I duplicate it's purpose?

For example, getting it to search for arrays before searching for variables...

```
        var a = {x:1, y:2};
        var x = 3;
        with (a) {
            console.log(x);
        }
```

The console would display 1.  But in strict mode, "with" would have to be removed.  If the console statement was outside of it, it would display 3.

Comment: Don't. They turn it off in strict mode for a reason. Or, disable strict mode.

Comment: How can I shoot myself in the foot with a locked gun? You can't. And that's the point!!!!

Comment: `with` is a nightmare. don't use it.

Comment: From the [with docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) - Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. See the "Ambiguity Con" paragraph in the "Description" section below for details.

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't. Don't think about using `with`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `with` as long as you understand it. Just like every other tool at our disposal. Let's drop the hysteria.

Comment: @cookiemonster - It creates ambiguity. For example, the `console.log` in the `with` should cause an error because there is no `a.console`, but it actually works.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: It shouldn't cause an error because of lexical variable scope. We wouldn't expect it to fail inside a function just because there's no local `console` variable in the function would we? This underscores the point I was trying to make with my first sentence. The only problem is with people not understanding the tools they use.

Comment: @cookiemonster - Lexical variable scope is one problem. There is no way to determine the existence of a property if the name exists outside the `with` scope.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Not sure what you mean on that one. Are you talking about shadowing variables like in the example above?

Comment: @cookiemonster - What I'm trying to say is, when `with` is used there is an ambiguity on what, for example, `console` means. It by definition should mean `a.console`, but because of the fact that it would assume it's referring to `window.console` if `a.console` did not exist, there is now 2 meanings for `console`. About the second comment I made, take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/34kfz/

Comment: *"It by definition should mean `a.console`..."* No, it shouldn't. It should behave like we would expect any other variable lookup to behave in a lexically scoped environment. It looks at the current scope, and when it doesn't find it, it proceeds to the outer scope, and continues on until the global scope. This isn't unique to the `with` statement.

Comment: ...in your demo, `location` doesn't not provide an unexpected result. Or at least no more unexpected than it would be in any other nested scope. Here's the a similar demo without the `with`. http://jsfiddle.net/34kfz/2/ Same result for `location`.

Comment: Now the question is, can I force a strict code to be non-strict? Imagine `'use non-strict';`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't**

From the [MDN with docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

> Using `with` is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose properties you want to access to a temporary variable.

Answer (score -1):

Strict mode redefines certain parts of Javascript with the intention of removing some ambiguities and incompatibilities. You **can't** `use strict` and then expect the affected language items to remain available.

The use of `with` leads to ambiguities in the scope of variables - already apparent in your example - and is not forward compatible with proposed standards in ES6 and beyond. You can find a fuller discussion on the MDN site [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

In your specific example you can always `console.log(a.x);`